# Find the type of derived object. Defining Dictionary with mixture of object types

Tags: c#

Here's what I have.

```
Class Parent
Class Child1
Class Child2
```

Both Child1 and Child2 derive from Parent.  Parent is not abstract and classes are NOT static.

I have two questions:

1) I want to be able to load Dictionary with a mixture of Parent, Child1 and Child2 objects.  What would be the syntax?

2) Later at runtime I would like to call a specific function of an object at a specific Dictionary index.  How would I know the type of object and access that function?

Comment: There is no such thing as _"a specific Dictionary index"_. .NET dictionary classes are unordered collections. As for the rest, it's not clear what you're asking. Dictionaries aren't different from anything else in the language with respect to base/derived class relationships. What have you tried? What _specifically_ are you having trouble with. Provide a good [mcve] that shows clearly answers to these questions.

Answer (score 0):

To declare a dictionary that will operate across those types you would declare a dictionary to operate with the base type (Parent)[This works the same way with many collection types in .NET such as List, etc]. An example:

```
var myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Parent>();
myDictionary.Add("1", new Child1);
myDictionary.Add("2", new Child2);
```

Later on you could iterate this dictionary, pull a key value pair out, and check the type of the object and do something specific with it.

```
foreach(var kvp in myDictionary){
     var currentObject = kvp.Value;
     if(currentObject.GetType() == typeof(Child1)){
         var currentAsChild1 = currentObject as Child1;
         //Do something special with this object a child1.
         //I would put this block into its own method probably.
     }
}
```

Dictionaries don't have what you would call an "index", and are instead key based. You could attempt to get the value of a specific key in the dictionary and perform similar logic to the logic displayed in the loop construct above.

```
Parent test;
if(myDictionary.TryGetValue("1", test){
   //Perform similar type checking logic here, cast the object to the derived type and perform the specific logic on that specific type.
}
```

A big consideration you need to make though is do you really need to do this. One suggestion I have is that you consider using an interface or an abstract class so you don't need to do this in the first place. Another question to ask yourself is are these derived types really derived types? Do they fit under the "is a" moniker for creating a derived type? If you can extract a common contract of methods to call I would either create an abstract method in the base class or implement an interface so you're not having to write logic like this, as it is very brittle (resistant to change).

Some basic overview bits on dictionaries can be found here with more examples on using them: [dotnetpearls](http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary)